# Kill screen session in an expect script

Tags: linux, expect, gnu-screen

I start my screen connection with a spawn command within an expect script:
spawn screen /dev/...

But I don't know how I can kill the screen when the script is finished

Answer (score 0):

```
screen -X quit
```

will send the `quit` command to the running screen session.

Comment: But it's still in the background

Answer (score 0):

try `screen -ls` then `screen -r  #process id` to enter the screen. Terminate it maybe using `ctrl + d`.